# How can I run Ubuntu 14.04 on a Ubuntu 16.04 pre-installed system?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

I am looking to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a machine that already runs 16.04, and have the option to choose the OS to run at boot up.  I recently purchased a System76 and that came with 16.04 pre-installed.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Installing 14.04 alongside 16.04 would do this. However since a computer that came with 16.04 preinstalled from system76 likely uses newer hardware. This could pose a problem with drivers but now that 14.04.5 with the hardware enablement stack is out it will use the same kernel and X stack as 16.04 so that will be less of a problem. Having two version of ubuntu installed side by side like this does work I use this quite a lot sometimes with the development version which of course is not supported here alongside the stable version. When you boot you can either use autoresize or try manual partitioning to resize with something else in the menu.